# NodeJS express-validator with passport

Tags: node.js, validation, passport.js

I write a signup form table, and I use `passport-local` is work, but I want add `express-validator` to validate my form data. I add validation on the router, this is my `router/index.js` code:

```
/* Handle Registration POST */
router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  req.assert('email', 'A valid email is required').isEmail();
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){   //No errors were found.  Passed Validation!
      res.render('register', {
        message: 'Mail type fault',
        errors: errors
      });
  }
  else
  {
    passport.authenticate('signup', {
      successRedirect: '/home',
      failureRedirect: '/signup',
      failureFlash : true
    });
  }
});
```

The validation is work, but if successful and then the web page will loading for a long time and no respond. I have search the passport doc, but no idea to fix it.

This is origin code, it's work

```
/* Handle Registration POST */
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
  successRedirect: '/home',
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  failureFlash : true
}));
```

I think I can use jquery to check out, but I don't do it. Because I just want to try use validator with passport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the validation in the LocalStrategy rather than the router should work just fine:

```
passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, username, password, callback) {
    /* do your stuff here */
    /* req.assert(...) */
}));
```

Answer (score 11):

Putting validation code in LocalStartegy should work but, personally I would first do authentication and once it has passed  use passport.

Consider something the following:

```
router.post('/login',function(req,res){

    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

    //validate 
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {

        res.render('signup',{user:null,frm_messages:errors});

    }
    else{
        passport.authenticate('login',{
            successRedirect:'/',
            failureRedirect: '/login',
            failureFlash : true  
        })(req,res); // <---- ADDD THIS
    }
});
```

Comment: I did this but It gave me error: TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function

Answer (score 4):

```
/* Handle Registration POST */
router.post('/signup', checkEmail,
    passport.authenticate('signup', {
      successRedirect: '/home',
      failureRedirect: '/signup',
      failureFlash : true
    });
});

function checkEmail(req, res, next){
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    //validate 
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.render('signup',{user:null,frm_messages:errors});
    } else {
      next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the the same problem exactly. I just used a middleware for checking validation, where i call next() in case validation is successful.

```
router.post("/login", 
  [check('email').isEmail().withMessage("A valid email is required")], 
  (req, res, next) => {
    // Check validation.
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // handle your error (redirect, render, ..).
    }
    // if validation is successful, call next() to go on with passport authentication.
    next();
  },
  passport.authenticate("login", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
  })
);
```